# Why does my SignalR app sometimes get disconnected

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I'm connecting to a signalR hub like this:

```
    $scope.starthubD = function() {
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            $.connection.HubName.server.method(sessionId);
        });
    };
```

I am receiving messages like this:

```
    $.connection.HubName.client.method= function(msg) {
        $scope.cars.push(msg);
    };
```

Through the hub, I am starting 10-12 long running threads:

```
public class ProcessHub: Hub
{
        IHubContext hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ProcessHub>();

        new Thread(() => new Process(connectionId, hubContext)).Start();
        new Thread(() => new Process2(connectionId, hubContext)).Start();
        new Thread(() => new Process3(connectionId, hubContext)).Start();
}
```

The threads themselves directly report back to the client using:

```
hubContext.Clients.Client(connectionId).report(data);
```

The issue I am having is that it works *most of the time*, but sometimes I get disconnected with this message:

> http://domain.se/signalr/connect?transport=serverSentEvents&connectionTok…weVsQoXvUzH&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22carcompare%22%7D%5D&tid=7
>   net::ERR_CONNECTION_

Comment: Do you have your server always up?

Comment: yes of course it's always up.

Comment: Provide more details about the server operating system, which transport are you using and enable logging: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#logging

Comment: isn't there something missing after ERR_CONNECTION_? e.g. ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found out what the issues was. One of the threads were throwing an exception, making connection to the hub being lost.

Comment: Though you solved your issue, you should provide a better answer to potentially help future visitors.  What about your code generated an error on the Thread, that caused the disconnect.

Comment: What in my code caused the exception? That is tied to the specified business logic and I can't really get into that as it's off-topic. 
But I can say: Any kind of exception(general) breaks the SignalR connection.